# Filling values in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net

I want to display result of select query in a `DataGridView` with where clause in query. The condition is specified in a label's value. i.e

```
select * 
from hospital_details 
where location_name= '" & Label6.Text & "'"
```

Following is the code

```
Public Sub fill()

    Try
        createConnection()
        da = New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim c As String
        c = Label6.Text
        comm.CommandText = "select * from hospital_details where location_name= '" & Label6.Text & "'"
        da.SelectCommand = comm
        da.Fill(ds, "hospital_details")
        DataGridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        DataGridView2.DataMember = "hospital_details"
        DataGridView2.ReadOnly = True

    Catch ex As Exception

        MsgBox("Error: " & ex.Source & ": " & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Connection Error !!")

    End Try

End Sub
```

But its showing error : `NullException`

Comment: Look into SQL Injection to avoid having your database hacked.

Comment: As for the exception: it's hard to say without pointing out the line that causes it, but I would guess that it's on the `c = Label6.Text`, `da.Fill(ds, "hospital_details")` or `DataGridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)` line. It's either that `Label6` is not initialized, `ds` is not initialized, or `DataGridView2` is not initialized, but I imagine that both `Label6` and `DataGridView2` come from a Code Behind file.

Comment: value appear for label 6 on same click event when result shows for DATAGRIDEVIEW

Comment: then how can i achieve this one ?

Comment: Well, to get it working, you just need to find the variable that has not been initialized, and initialize it. Since you're almost certainly in Visual Studio, you should be able to launch your project in Debug mode and look for the value set to `Nothing` (`null` in C#, hence `NullException` is the name); I suggest looking at `ds` to see where it's instantiated. To prevent SQL Injection, you should be using [SQL Parameters](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/113/Preventing-SQL-Injection-in-ASP.NET).

Comment: Me.Hospital_detailsTableAdapter1.FillBy(Me.PpDataSet1.hospital_details, Label6.Text)

Comment: As the example code is not the actual code, you should be able to use the `NullException` to find out the line number of the error as well, which should center it around the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can load data from sql server , follow the link
http://mssqlguid.blogspot.in/2013/07/how-to-load-data-into-datagridview-from.html